# How does an HTTPProxySocket work?

Tags: proxy

**Background**

I'm trying to figure out what's going on in a proxy server implementation I found online [here](https://github.com/zhuhaow/NEKit/blob/master/src/ProxyServer/GCDHTTPProxyServer.swift) but am quite lost. I was able to run the proxy successfully, but I am unable to understand what is happening under the hood. I'll explain what exactly I'm confused about in just a moment.

**What I have done so far**

I was able to start the proxy server described in [this class](https://github.com/zhuhaow/NEKit/blob/master/src/ProxyServer/GCDHTTPProxyServer.swift) and redirected my HTTP traffic there. I am able to successfully load pages in my browser through the proxy.

**Where I am confused**

The socket that is opened when a connection is received by the proxy server is of type [HTTPProxySocket](https://github.com/zhuhaow/NEKit/blob/master/src/Socket/ProxySocket/HTTPProxySocket.swift). Within this socket, data is passed to the remote server, and when data is read back, an HTTPStreamScanner (line 127) is used to scan the response data.

But I'm able to see both HTTP and HTTPS header data, which is really confusing to me.

**Question**

- It seems like HTTP Connect is being used. After a little digging, it seems like CONNECT is used to initialize a tunnel. Really, I'm over my head with this. How does a tunnel relate to a socket, and why would I want to create a tunnel in the first place?
- At what layer of the network model does this operate? Or does that question not even make sense?

Comment: The data is not encrypted when arriving to the proxy, but encrypted later when it connects to the destination. For more information you will need to ask on StackOverflow.

Comment: Well, it *is* supposed to be encrypted for HTTPS connections (if the browser uses HTTP CONNECT, which I think most do, then the raw TLS data is transferred)...

Comment: @grawity I had never heard of HTTP CONNECT, but I'm looking into it now. It seems like you're right...the rest of the header is encrypted.

Comment: I would expect you to see the hostname+port (which are TCP parameters and remain visible in proxy CONNECT requests), but not the /path nor ?query nor the method (GET/POST) nor additional headers (which are HTTP parameters and should be encrypted). Please confirm if that's what you are seeing.

Comment: @grawity yes this is exactly right, thanks! I've got a very short time to figure out what's going on here, and you seem to understand quite well. Happy to accept an answer if you write one :) I'll update the "Question" part of my question now that I've got a little direction from you.

Comment: @grawity updated. Thank you for helping to save me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of how encrypted the HTTPS connection might be, at minimum the proxy needs to know:

1. the server's address (usually the IP address, but many browsers send the full hostname – in case the proxy might have different DNS settings),
2. the TCP port to connect to (generally 443 for HTTPS).

According to your comments, that's the only information you are seeing, so this is normal. The browser won't be sending HTTP-specific parameters (original request method, path, query string, HTTP headers) until it establishes the TLS connection to the server, through your proxy.

---

> Really, I'm over my head with this. How does a tunnel relate to a socket, and why would I want to create a tunnel in the first place? [...] At what layer of the network model does this operate? Or does that question not even make sense?

*(This is a general description, not a NEKit-oriented description.)*

In networks, a tunnel is something that pretends to be at a lower layer than it really is, and is able to carry same-layer or even lower-layer protocols inside itself.

For example, regular HTTP is an application-layer protocol, but HTTP CONNECT allows it to carry *other* application-layer protocols inside – to the web browser it behaves like a transport protocol, in the sense that you can build connect()/send()/recv() functions around it.

As another example, most VPNs are a type of tunnel that carries IP inside UDP, i.e. L3 over L4. (Maybe even L3-over-L7 if you include the encryption/compression/authentication stuff that the VPN does.)

(TLS itself is quite similar. If you're looking from the transport layer's point of view, TLS is an application layer protocol, but if you look from the application's perspective, TLS could very well be the upper-half of transport layer.)

So why would you want to create a tunnel? To break the layering, that's literally it. Your original question was, "why does the proxy seem to break HTTPS encryption". That's exactly why HTTP CONNECT is used – browsers use it to carry a lower-layer protocol (TLS) inside a higher-layer protocol (HTTP) in order to *preserve the encryption.*

Comment: Ok, I _think_ that makes sense. So when I designate that my browser should be using a web proxy, it will decide to use HTTP CONNECT in order to pass information (such as hostname / port) so that the proxy server knows what to do with it, without needing to see the raw TCP/IP packets themselves?

Comment: Without needing to see the raw HTTP requests (URLs&headers) themselves, rather, but yes.

Comment: Ah ok.. I think I'm almost there.. So although the headers at the IP packet level also contain destination IP/port information, that is unimportant in this context because this proxy server isn't really operating at the level that sees IP packets? It's operating at the application (socket?) level.